# chart.setOptions is not defined

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have highcharts 4.0.3 where I need to  modify the tooltipo object dynamically.

When I use chart.setOptions, console says that setOptions is not defined.

```
chart.setOptions({
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} (porcentaje): <b>{point.percentage:.1f} %</b><br />{series.name} (unidades): <b>{point.y}</b>'
            },
        });
```

How can I do that without updating to highcharts 5.0?

Comment: try calling your `chart` object from the console and see the properties available to it, if the `setOptions` is not there, then that's the problem.

Comment: Make sure you have defined `chart` before you try and call the `setOptions` methods.

Comment: chart is defined before.. and in fact setTitle called just before setOptions does work

Answer (score 0):

`setOptions` is a method on the `Highcharts` object, not the `Chart` object.  `Highcharts.setOptions` (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Highcharts.setOptions) sets the options for all charts **created after** this has been called.

I assume your chart variable is an instance of a chart.  If you want to modify an existing chart, you use the update method.

```
  chart.update({
    series: {
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name} (porcentaje): <b>{point.percentage:.1f} %</b><br />{series.name} (unidades): <b>{point.y}</b>'
      }
    }
  });
```

**Note that I am setting the tooltip on the series.**  If you have mutliple series, you will need to set each one.

http://jsfiddle.net/doere5sy/